# Android ValueAnimator API 19

Tags: android, animation, resume

I am using the ValueAnimator with a SeekBar view. When the user stops dragging the seekbar thumb, the animator pauses and when the user drags it again, seekbar resumes.

The problem is when I call resume on the animation, the getAnimatedFraction() & getAnimatedValue() values are being reset as if the animation is starting from the beginning. Is this how the ValueAnimator should behave?

Here's a snippet of my seekbar code:

```
       public void onStartTrackingTouch(final SeekBar seekBar) {

            if(animation.isStarted() && animation.getAnimatedFraction() != 1L){
                animation.resume();
            }

        }

        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            animation.pause();               
        }
```

Comment: maybe I am missing something, does the animation track your touch?

Answer (score -1):

You need to tell the animation to keep the end value.

```
animation.setFillAfter(true);
```

This should work.

Comment: `ValueAnimator` doesn't have a `setFillAfter()` method.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was a view.Animation object.